# Why does this query ignore fields containing USA?

Tags: php, sql

I know there's a wizard out there who can answer this ...

I have a PHP / MySQL database that lists over 500 wines. Using a form, web visitors can search the database by wine name, country, vintage, etc.

I have tested two (2) different queries.

The one I want to use refuses to return a **country specific** search for USA, but has NO problem with Spain, Australia, Italy, Canada or Chile (or even United States - which I tested) .

USA only shows up when the user enters a **wine name** or **vintage**, etc., that happens to match a USA product. Otherwise, it treats USA like it doesn't exist.

The other code (bottom block) returns all USA searches, but does not search across multiple columns / terms, which I need.

1. This code WILL NOT find a country-specific search for USA

   ```
      $cob=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user-entry']);

   // remove the line below to prevent searching multiple terms
      $cob = '+' . str_replace(' ',' +',$cob);

     $sql = sprintf ( 
     "SELECT CSPC, Country, Producer, Wine, Year, Price,
     MATCH ( CSPC, Country, Producer, Wine, Year ) 
     AGAINST ( '&s' IN BOOLEAN MODE )  
     FROM winecellar WHERE 
     MATCH ( CSPC, Country, Producer, Wine, Year ) 
     AGAINST ( '%s' IN BOOLEAN MODE )", $cob, $cob ) . $pricerange;
   ```
2. This code WILL find a country-specific search for USA

   ```
     $cob=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user-entry']);

     $sql="SELECT ID, CSPC, Country, Producer, Wine, Year, Price 
     FROM winecellar WHERE
     ( CSPC LIKE '%" . $cob .  "%' 
     OR Country LIKE '%" . $cob ."%' 
     OR Producer LIKE '%" . $cob ."%' 
     OR Wine LIKE '%" . $cob ."%' 
     OR Year LIKE '%" . $cob ."%' )" . $pricerange;
   ```

   - MySQL Server version: 5.1.65-cll
   - Country = varchar (20)
   - Country = NULL No
   - Full-Text Index: Country, Producer, Wine, Year

So my question is, what is preventing the multi-term code (in the top block) from recognizing USA as a valid query?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks guys.

Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a `FULLTEXT` index.  The default minimum word length is 4.  Three letter words are ignored.  [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html) is the reference for changing defaults.

Comment: Thanks so much dnagirl, I should have guessed. I'll see what I can do. Back in a bit ..

Comment: I changed the FULL TEXT index to exclude the Country column, and it's still not finding USA properly. Any thoughts on how I might modify the PHP query? - see code above, thanks.

Comment: @user1515259: I'd suggest changing how your user submits a country.  Make them use a picklist or an exclusive auto-complete so that the country can be an exact rather than fuzzy comparison.  Then you can use `WHERE country='USA'`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I'm not sure I could properly code either of them, but I'll see what I can come up with, much appreciated :)

Comment: Hi dnagirl, just thought I'd let you know, my web-host changed the min word length to "3" for me. Works beautifully! So, thanks a bunch for your help. Cheers, Chris.